# Inclusion of non events in survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I am a newbie to survival analysis. I am trying to understand whether it is important to include measurements at which nothing was observed into a data set.

I have the following fictive data: three patients,

1. the first patient is observed with a illness at time 12,
2. the second is observed twice once at time 13 and once at time 14 to have no illness, and
3. the third patient is observed to have an illness at time 1.

I tried the two following examples

```
require(flexsurv)
surv_test <- with(data.frame(status = c(1,0,0,1), time = c(12L, 13L,1L, 1L)), Surv(time, status))
flexsurvreg(surv_test~1, dist = "weibull")

#Call:
#flexsurvreg(formula = surv_test ~ 1, dist = "weibull")

#Estimates: 
#          est    L95%    U95%      se    
#shape   0.937   0.295   2.973   0.552
#scale  13.755   3.001  63.035  10.683

#N = 4,  Events: 2,  Censored: 2
#Total time at risk: 27
#Log-likelihood = -7.199135, df = 2
#AIC = 18.39827
```

and

```
surv_test <- with(data.frame(status = c(1,0,1), time = c(12L, 14L, 1L)), Surv(time, status))
flexsurvreg(surv_test~1, dist = "weibull")

#Call:
#flexsurvreg(formula = surv_test ~ 1, dist = "weibull")

#Estimates: 
#          est    L95%    U95%      se    
#shape   0.844   0.244   2.922   0.535
#scale  13.883   2.635  73.140  11.770

#N = 3,  Events: 2,  Censored: 1
#Total time at risk: 27
#Log-likelihood = -7.167346, df = 2
#AIC = 18.33469
```

The results show that there is a clear difference between the two, I was wondering whether someone can explain why it is important to include observations that the patient is not ill. Thanks!

Comment: the first data set has four patients and the second has three. why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: It is important to include non-events (ie. observations of healthy subjects) in survival analysis but typically you only include the last time you observed any patient and their status at that time (e.g. for patient #2 only include that they were healthy at time 14). You may want to do some reading on the topic of censoring in survival analysis.

Comment: thanks @tsurudak . Do you have any recommendations on literature?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit rusty with my survival analysis so I don't have great recommendations. But since your question is more of a stats question than a programming question, you might find better help on Cross Validated: [e.g. this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/references-for-survival-analysis)